# Adding a <script> as a node value in Html Dom not working

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

why the script not working in the example below (not working :i.e the script is not excuting in the browser)

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query( "//div[@class = 'ad_stream_hd']");
foreach( $nodes as $node) {
$node->nodeValue = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clkrev.com/adServe/banners?tid=SPORTVE158X21&size=158x21" ></script>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The node value is just text, its not like inner HTML where you can specify a string with markup in it. With a document fragment you can get something close to that, but you're setting xml rather than html so your html would have to be valid xml.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query( "//div[@class = 'ad_stream_hd']");
if ($nodes->length > 0){
    $node = $nodes->item($nodes->length-1);
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clkrev.com/adServe/banners?tid=SPORTVE158X21&amp;size=158x21" ></script>');
    $node->appendChild($fragment);
}
```

Comment: when doing it your way i got syntax error, unexpected ';' in this line $fragment->appendXML('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clkrev.com/adServe/banners?tid=SPORTVE158X21&amp;size=158x21" ></script>';);

Comment: You have excessive semicolon at the end of `$fragment->appendXML`: `;);` → `);`

Comment: @Musa i found an issue with this method just now in the footer of the page containing the code above i have thsi script `     <script src="http://clkrev.com/adServe/banners?tid=SPORTVE800X440SL&size=800x440&type=slider&side=center" type='text/javascript'></script>` now after adding your code to the dom the last script is executed and show twice in the page what cause this and how to avoid??

Comment: @Musa please help me with comment above

Comment: @mirandakerry are there multiple divs with class `ad_stream_hd`

Comment: @mirandakerry You are adding the tag multiple times, just add it once. See updated answer.

Comment: @Musa but the updated answer doesn't work at all please note that the div that already have the class `ad_stream_hd` is having content and what i am adding here is replacement for this content so i was using `$node->nodeValue = '';` before adding the tag using your answer but the updated answer doesn't work with this way

Comment: @Musa please help me with comment above

Comment: @Musa no error msgs but nothing replace and original content of the div is there

Comment: @Musa please help me with comment above

Comment: Musa please help me with comment above

Comment: @mirandakerry empty out the empty out the div in a loop but only add one script to the last div.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** right way to iterate DOMNodeList:

```
$nodes_length = $nodes->length;
for ($i=0; $i < $nodes_length; $i++) { 
    $nodes->item($i)->nodeValue = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clkrev.com/adServe/banners?tid=SPORTVE158X21&size=158x21" ></script>';
}
```

Comment: i got annot use object of type DOMNodeList as array in in line (    $nodes[$key]->nodeValue = '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://clkrev.com/adServe/banners?tid=SPORTVE158X21&size=158x21" ></script>';) while using the 1st code

Comment: `$nodes->length` is calculated on each iteration. better put that in a var `$len = $nodes->length`